# Finding the antiderivatives of a function with an absolute value solution verification

Tags: calculus, analysis, solution-verification

I was asked to find the antiderivatives in $\mathbb{R}$ of the following function: $$f(x)=\frac{|e^x-1|}{e^{2x}+1}$$

---

What I did was the following: I started considering the restriction of f to $[0, +\infty[,$ thus evaluating $$\int \frac{e^x-1}{e^{2x}+1}dx=\arctan(e^x)+ \frac{1}{2}\log(e^{2x}+1) -x +c_1$$ (I'm using $\log$ for $\ln$). Then I did the same thing when $x \in ]-\infty,0[$, obviously $\int f_{|]-\infty,0[}(x)dx=-\int f_{|[0,+\infty[}(x)dx$
, so we can conclude that $$F(x)=\begin{cases}\arctan(e^x)+ \frac{1}{2}\log(e^{2x}+1) -x +c_1, \ x>0\\-[\arctan(e^x)+ \frac{1}{2}\log(e^{2x}+1) -x]+c_2, \ x<0\end{cases}$$ Now, since $F$ has to be derivable everywhere in $\mathbb{R}$, it has to be continuous in $x=0$, so $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0^+}F(x)=\frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{1}{2} \log(2)+c_1=F(0)$ but also $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0^-}F(x)=- \frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{2} \log2+c_2=F(0)$;

So we conclude that $c_2=\frac{\pi}{2} + \log(2)+c_1$. So the antiderivatives of $f$ can be written as $$F(x)=\begin{cases}\arctan(e^x)+ \frac{1}{2}\log(e^{2x}+1) -x +c_1, \ x>0\\ \frac{\pi}{4} +\frac{1}{2} \log(2)+c_1, \ x=0 \\-[\arctan(e^x)+ \frac{1}{2}\log(e^{2x}+1) -x] +\frac{\pi}{2} + \log(2)+c_1, \ x<0\end{cases}$$

---

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^-}F(x)=-\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\log 2}{2}-c_2$, not $+c_2$.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I forgot to close the parenthesis before $c_2$, but now I've fixed it

Comment: your last expression for $F(x)$ also has wrong brackets placement then. In the end it should be $c_1+ \text{piecewise stuff}$

Comment: Yeah I've just noticed and fixed it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct, addressing the relation between $c_1$ and $c_2$ was the key point.

You can rewrite it a bit more simply as

$$F(x)=\begin{cases}\arctan(e^x)+ \frac{1}{2}\log(e^{2x}+1) -x +c_1, \ x>0 \\-[\arctan(e^x)+ \frac{1}{2}\log(e^{2x}+1) -x] +\frac{\pi}{2} + \log(2)+c_1, \ x \leq 0\end{cases}$$